# In swagger file configuration it's possibile to get 2 parameters in path

Tags: python, connexion

I have a problem with Flask, Connexion and Swagger yaml file. I must define a path as: `/price/{code1}/{code2}`.

In my yaml file I have set the root path as:

```
paths:
  /price/{code1}/{code2}:
    get:
      operationId: lib.pack.test
      parameters:
      - in: path
        name: code1
        required: true
        type: string
        description: "code 1"
      - in: path
        name: code2
        reguired: true
        type: string
        description: "code 2"
```

When I execute `server.py` I obtain this error:

```
connexion.exceptions.InvalidSpecification: {'reguired': True, 'in': 'path', 'type': 'string', 'description': 'code 2', 'name': 'code'} is not valid under any of the given schemas

Failed validating 'oneOf' in schema['properties']['paths']['patternProperties']['^/']['properties']['get']['properties']['parameters']['items']:
    {'oneOf': [{'$ref': '#/definitions/parameter'},
               {'$ref': '#/definitions/jsonReference'}]}

On instance['paths']['/price/{code1}/{code2}']['get']['parameters'][1]:
    {'description': 'code 2',
     'in': 'path',
     'name': 'code2',
     'reguired': True,
     'type': 'string'}
```

If I remove `{code2}` the server starts correctly.

- Python 2.7
- Flask 1.0.2
- Connexion 2.2.0

This is my code:

Server.py

```
from flask import render_template
import connexion

# Create the application instance
app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir="configuration/")
app.add_api('swagger.yml')
app.run(port=5000, debug=True)


# Create a URL route in our application for "/"
@app.route('/')
def home():
    """
    This function just responds to the browser ULR
    localhost:5000/

    :return:        the rendered template 'home.html'
    """
    return render_template('home.html')


# If we're running in stand alone mode, run the application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

And this is the Yaml

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: This is the swagger file that goes with our server code
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: Server crawler REST
consumes:
  - "application/json"
produces:
  - "application/json"

basePath: "/api"

paths:
  /avgprice/{code1}/{code2}:
    get:
      operationId: "lib.pack.test"
      tags:
        - "Avgprice"
      summary: "Avg price"
      description: "Calculator system to define AVG price from code1/code2"
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: code1
          required: true
          type: string
        - in: path
          name: code2
          reguired: true
          type: string
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Successful"
          schema:
            type: "array"
            items:
              properties:
                id_code1:
                  type: "integer"
                code1:
                  type: "string"
                id_code2:
                  type: "integer"
                code2:
                  type: "string"
                price:
                  type: "integer"
```

Comment: can you put your code pls?

Comment: I add my code..

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution :)

I was wrong to write the file YAML

```
- in: path
  name: code2
  **reguired: true** <-- required: true
  type: string
  description: "code 2"
```